# how to retrieve object from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to retrieve an elements of object from an array

I tried with but didn't get

```
  $api_response_decode['data']->stdClass->sales->stdClass
```

here is my array

```
 [data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sales] => stdClass Object
            (
                [clothing] => 2
                [men] => 0
                [children] => 4
            )

    )
```

I want to get

```
 [clothing]
 [men]
 [children]
```

Comment: `stdClass` is the object type, not the attribute name....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `stdClass` in your example:

To get the object:

```
$api_response_decode['data']
```

To get the sales object:

```
$api_response_decode['data']->sales
```

To get, say, clothing:

```
$api_response_decode['data']->sales->clothing
```

Comment: still get annot use object of type stdClass as array :(

Comment: @user2046638 If `$api_response_decode` is an object also you will have to treat it like one: `$api_response_decode->data`

Answer (score 1):

is $api_response_decode an object or an array? How are you getting it?

However, you could retrieve the sales items with [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-object-vars.php).

```
$items=get_object_vars($api_response_decode->data->sales);
var_dump($items);
```

prints

```
array(3) {
  ["clothing"]=>   int(2)
  ["men"]=>    int(0)
  ["children"]=>  int(4)
}
```

Edit: it seems `$api_response_decode` is an object, so I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

stdClass is a type, not a value.

```
$api_response_decode['data']->sales->clothing
```

This subject can give you more informations of what stdClass is and how to use it : [What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

Comment: still get cannot use object of type stdClass as array :(

Comment: Give a var_dump() of $api_response_decode. Maybe data is also an object and not an array.