# Sending json in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am trying to send json in ajax using javascript. I am able to retrieve the values back from php but unable to retrieve a specific json array.

```
var mname = ["john", "mary", "eva"];
var fname = 678;
clicked_keyword_test = {"lastName": fname, "firstName": mname};
xmlhttp.send('myArray=' +JSON.stringify(clicked_keyword_test));
```

Getting data in PHP and sending it back to ajax:

```
 $receive_data = json_decode ($_POST['myArray']); 
 echo json_encode($receive_data);
```

Now the above works fine but if I want to retrieve only the values of `"firstName"` like `echo json_encode($receive_data["firstName"]);` then I get an error like:

```
 <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in.....
```

How can I sucessfully send json data using javascript not jquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the second parameter of `json_decode` to true in order to return an associative array.

```
$receive_data = json_decode ($_POST['myArray'], true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

In *PHP* `stdClass` is the base class from which all other objects are derived.  All objects in deserialised *JSON* data assume this type as no other definition is communicated.  Properties of objects are accessed using the following notation:

```php
$dataObj->varName;
```

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) also has an optional second parameter which coerces objects to associative-arrays which is how you are trying to access the property.