# Assigning Keys and Values to Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, key

I have the following which assigns the values I need to an array in php

```
 $resultsAr[$row['stop_name']][$row['route_long_name']][] = $row['arrival_time'];
```

However when I convert this to JSON it does not have any keys.

```
echo json_encode($resultsAr);
```

e.g.

```
{
Stop1: {
Destination1: [
"11:13",
"11:25"
],
Destination2: [
"11:15",
"11:27"
],
Destination3: [
"11:14",
"11:23",
"11:26"
]
},
```

They keys are actually the values. How can I assign key names to the array?

Edited: the required JSON output would be keys with values:

```
[Stops => all stops] [destinations => destinations] [times => arrival times]
```

Comment: What would be the desired JSON output ? It's quite unclear

Comment: The `json_encode();` worked perfectly fine. The array structure specified, is being represented by the JSON you've sent us. What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: @ClémentMalet I've updated the question - I want to include keys with in the array - not use the stop/destination names as keys

Comment: @ZanderRootman yes it has encoded fine - just want to include key names so that when I decode it I can reference them

Comment: Try when you decode `json_decode($json, true);` Also, "Stop1", "Destination1" ect. are your Array "Keys". So your keys are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be set key for array when you want to encode array to json

Example:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
       $resultsAr[$row['stop_name']][$row['route_long_name']][$i] = $row['arrival_time'];
       $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->name = "Stop1";
$obj->data = array(
    array("Destination1",array("11:13","11:25")),
    array("Destination2",array("11:13","11:25")),
    array("Destination3",array("11:13","11:25")),
    );

echo json_encode($obj);
```

On a side note Only numeric items can appear without quotation. [json.org](http://www.json.org/)

Also to explain stdclass - [What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)