# WordPress custom taxonomy page stdclass notice

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, notice

I'm trying to add custom taxonomy to a custom post type in WordPress. When wp_debig is enabled the wp-admin page throws a notice:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$taxonomy in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/admin-bar.php on line 503

in the line 503 there is only this:

```
 && ( $tax = get_taxonomy( $tag->taxonomy ) )
```

My custom taxonomy is like this:

```
    function create_project_types(){
        $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Project Type', 'abc'),
            'singular_name' => __('Project Type', 'abc'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Project Types', 'abc'),
            'all_items' => __('All Project Types', 'abc'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Project Type', 'abc'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Project Type', 'abc'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project Type', 'abc'),
            'new_item_name' => __('New Project Type', 'abc'),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate Types with commas', 'abc'),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or Remove Project Type', 'abc'),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from Most Used Project Types', 'abc')
        );
        $args = array(
            'label' => __('Project Type', 'abc'),
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            "hierarchical" => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'project-type','with_front' => true),
            'query_var' => true
        );
        register_taxonomy("project-type", 'project', $args);
    }
add_action('init', 'create_project_types', 0);
```

Everything is working properly I'm just trying to dismiss that notice. Can You help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. I overwited the global $tag variable, and this couse the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Notices are not errors. Depending on context they could mean something its wrong, though.

If you are leaving the house and you->keys is undefined, you have a problem, but if you->pocketlint were undefined instead, maybe its no big deal. Maybe its pretty expected, because its your new coat. :)

Your code is saying something like:

"If wallet exists and wallet have money then buy icecream"

Note that if the code absolutely-have-to-get-icecream-or-die, then it should not let things carry on without it. It should die appropriately.

Of course, poorly written code that lets the program jump_from_plane() with !$parachute. 
Its just doesn't seems to me to be the case.

If all things are working fine and code isn't making a fuss about it, neither should you.

SO DISMISS THE NOTICE. You have my permission. If anything goes wrong you may say I told you so.

Some things related you should read if you didn't get some or any thing of the above:

$tag is a stdClass object. [See what stdClass is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php).

You turned on debug mode, so you said. Check [PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Debug mode set error reporting up high, so you'll get ERRORs, WARNINGs and NOTICEs.

BUT:

Anyways, if you are so annoyed by it, replace `$tax = get_taxonomy( $tag->taxonomy )` with `$tax = property_exists($tag, 'taxonomy') ? get_taxonomy( $tag->taxonomy ) : false`

Comment: the full part of the admin-bar.php file which belongs here:
`global $tag, $wp_the_query;
if ( is_admin() ) {
$current_screen = get_current_screen();
$post = get_post();
.
.
.
} elseif ( 'edit-tags' == $current_screen->base
&& isset( $tag ) && is_object( $tag )
&& ( $tax = get_taxonomy( $tag->taxonomy ) )
&& $tax->public )
{
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
'id' => 'view',
'title' => $tax->labels->view_item,
'href' => get_term_link( $tag )
) );
}`

Comment: Have anything missing in the admin bar? If not you are good to go. Check [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar/add_menu)

Comment: nothing. everything is on the right position. even the custom post types under the "new" menu item.

Comment: it only appears when i add term to a taxonomy. if there's no term, there's no notice...