# Editing a poorly formatted JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a site which I used JSON to save some data.

Here is how it saves data

```
{"1":{"english":{"grade":"7","time":"79"},"physics":{"grade":"3","time":"48"}}}
```

**Note:** I know this is a poor way of doing it but I did it when I was not so vast!

The `1` is the `user_id` which changes according to the id of the user that takes an exam on the platform. The `english`, `physics` are the subjects this user took.

The maximum number of exam a user can take at a time is for so the `json` string will look like `{"1":{"english":{"grade":"7","time":"79"},"physics":{"grade":"3","time":"48"},"maths":{"grade":"7","time":"79"},"chemistry":{"grade":"3","time":"48"}}}`

First I think this is the best way to save the result as a `JSON` string

```
[{"subject":"english","grade":"7","time":"79"}, {"subject":"physics", "grade":"3","time":"48"}}]
```

My problem is that I want to use PHP to work on the former on. I have done some few stripping of the string and I'm left with this `{"english":{"grade":"7","time":"79"},"physics":{"grade":"3","time":"48"}}`

I tried this chunk

```
$JSONResult = json_decode($aScore->result);
foreach ($JSONResult as $subjectKey => $aSubject)
{
    foreach ($aSubject as $theResult)
    {
        $userResult = '
        Subject: **This is what I've not been able to get**
        Grade: '.$theResult->grade.'
        Time: '.$theResult->time.'
        ';
    }
}
```

I tried `$aSubject->subjectKey` to get the associative key value from the first `foreach` statement but it did not work

Any help?

**Added: Please leave comments about the way the `JSON` string was stored. I'd love to learn.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the inner loop. Each subject is just a single object, not an array. And the subject key is just `$subjectKey`, it's not a part of the object.

```
$JSONResult = json_decode($aScore->result, true); // to get an associative array rather than objects
foreach ($JSONResult as $subjectKey => $aSubject) {
    $userResult = "
        Subject: $subjectKey
        Grade: {$aSubject['grade']}
        Time: {$aSubject['time']}
    ";
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/JdH0Jg)

Comment: Here is what I get when I removed the inner loop `Undefined index: grade `

Comment: My answer is based on the JSON in the question after "I'm left with this"

Answer (score 0):

You could use the second argument to [`json_decode!`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

It changes your `$JSONResult` from [`stdClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) to an [associative `Array!`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Which means you can do something like this:

```
$str = '{"1":{"english":{"grade":"7","time":"79"},"physics":{"grade":"3","time":"48"}}}';

$result = json_decode($str, true); // Put "true" in here!

echo "<pre>".print_r($result, true)."</pre>"; // Just for debugging!
```

Which would output this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [english] => Array
        (
            [grade] => 7
            [time] => 79
        )
        [physics] => Array
        (
            [grade] => 3
            [time] => 48
        )
    )
)
```

And in order to loop through it:

```
foreach ($result as $idx => $exams) {

    echo $exams['english']['grade']."<br>";
    echo $exams['physics']['grade']."<br>";

}
```

Which would output this:

```
7
3
```

---

### Update

Without knowing the containing arrays data (Based on the example above)

`$exams` will be an `Array` (which could contain any sort of information):

```
Array
(
    [english] => Array
    (
        [grade] => 7
        [time] => 79
    )
    [physics] => Array
    (
        [grade] => 3
        [time] => 48
    )
)
```

If you want to loop through `$exams`:

```
foreach ($result as $idx => $exams) {

    foreach ($exams as $subject => $info) {

        echo $info['grade']."<br>";

    }

}
```

This would produce the same output as the above example, without needing to know a subject name!

Comment: This may fail from your final chunk because I don't know the exam subjects a user will pick so the $val['english']['grade'] should be something like $val[$subject]['grade]. What do you think?

Comment: I said I stripped the string and am left with this `{"english":{"grade":"7","time":"79"},"physics":{"grade":"3","time":"48"}}` how do I go about it from here not from the original one you set as your variable in your answer.