# How get a value of my array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
  array(3) {
      ["formData"]=>
      array(25) {
        ["Contact.Name.First"]=>
        object(stdClass)#17 (2) {
          ["value"]=>
          string(31) "POLIANA KRUSCHER PISCOLLE"
          ["required"]=>
          bool(true)
        }
        ["Contact.CustomFields.c.new_cpf"]=>
        object(stdClass)#21 (2) {
          ["value"]=>
          string(14) "038.889.971-99"
          ["required"]=>
          bool(true)
        }
    }
```

How can I retrieve ***value*** in ***Contact.CustomFields.c.new_cpf***?

I tried `$incident_data['Contact.CustomFields.c.new_cpf']['value']`, but it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$incident_data['formData']['Contact.CustomFields.c.new_cpf']->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$incident_data['formData']['Contact.CustomFields.c.new_cpf']` does not contain an array yet you try to access it as such.

Since there is no such key php defaults to `null`. (Yet there also should be an undefined index notice thrown around. You may want to enhance your error logging / strictness level).

As by your dump you have an of the [`\stdClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) class, you have to treat them as such:

```
$object->value
```