# Convert php array to object $this

Tags: php, arrays, object, this

I have keys and values as follows :

```
[store_id] => 1
[store_name] => StarShop
[store_phone] => 62-22-8383838
[store_email] => admin@starshop.com
```

I use this to make objects with $this from the above arrays

```
foreach($above_array as $key => $value){
  $this->$key = $value;
}

echo $this->store_name; // this does not work, please help
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php

Comment: so far this is a just a story, whats your question?

Comment: Does this code appear within a class?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$this->`, if you are not inside a class:

```
<?php

$a = array(
'store_id' => 1,
'store_name' => 'StarShop',
'store_phone' => '62-22-8383838',
'store_email] => admin@starshop.com',
);

$obj = new StdClass;               // create new object
foreach($a as $key => $value){     // iterate as before
  $obj->$key = $value;             // add properties to object
}

echo $obj->store_name; 

?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/552253)

Comment: so $this is only for static variable?

Comment: `$this` always refers to the instance of the class your code is inside of.