# Example of Multidimensional Array using the MVC framework - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Would anyone have a good example of a hard coded Multidimensional array using Codeigniter.  The examples I've seen use a database, but I'm looking for an example that is hard coded.

Thanks

Greg

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Arrays are PHP and not framework specific. This question / request does not belong here. Best would be to change your question to note down a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('one' => array('sub1' => 42, 'sub2' => 90310), 
              'two' => array('sub1' => 321, 'sub2' => 10122));
```

Same thing with "short syntax"

```
$data = [
        'one' => ['sub1' => 42, 'sub2' => 90310], 
        'two' => ['sub1' => 321, 'sub2' => 10122]
        ];
```

Comment: Does that go into the Model sections, and what is the code for the controller?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of array

1. Array like @DFriend answer
2. Array objects

use `print_r($arrayName);` so that you can see the array structure.

For an example, let's say you getting result from the database. and if you use `$result = $query->result();` you will get an array object and if you use `$result = $query->result_array();` you will get 2D array.

those two array will be like below, (@DFriend example)

2D Array

```
$data = array('one' => array('sub1' => 42, 'sub2' => 90310), 
              'two' => array('sub1' => 321, 'sub2' => 10122));
```

Array Object [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
    stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [id] => 25 
        [time] => 2014-01-16 16:35:17 
        [fname] => 4 
        [text] => 5 
        [url] => 6 
    ),
[1] => 
    stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [id] => 25
        [time] => 2014-01-17 16:35:17 
        [fname] => 45
        [text] => 55
        [url] => 66
    ) 
)
```

Comment: PM-Riable, What you call "Array objects" is a 1D array. To be multidimensional an array must containing one or more additional arrays. Your "Array objects" contains multiple Objects (a.k.a. classes) but Objects are not arrays.

Comment: Yes it is and I accept with you. In the question Greg_C mentioned **examples I've seen use a database** so I talked about one another way of use database results.