# Getting single result from array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

```
object(stdClass)#19 (2) { 
    ["status"] =>
        string(7) "success" 
    ["data"] =>
        object(stdClass)#14 (6) {
                ["network"] => 
                    string(3) "BTC" 
                ["txid"] =>
                    string(64) "128830010b4773bb9a88f9c53b67217f37caa092bfd477a81a2f41d6ea804e53"
                ["amount_withdrawn"] =>
                    string(10) "0.00087298"
                ["amount_sent"] =>
                    string(10) "0.00050000"
                ["network_fee"] =>
                    string(10) "0.00037298"
                ["blockio_fee"] =>
                    string(10) "0.00000000"
        }
}
```

I have this array but I a struggling to find out how to get data from it such as txid, Im not sure whether its json or.. Help would be appreciated

Comment: It's an object, not an array. So use $object->data->txid

Answer (score 0):

The original variable is a [stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php). The output you posted looks like it's from [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Formatting your code a little better shows how you can get data from the *original variable*.

```
object(stdClass)#19 (2) { 
    ["status"]=> string(7) "success" 
    ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#14 (6) { 
        ["network"]=> string(3) "BTC" 
        ["txid"]=> string(64) "128830010b4773bb9a88f9c53b67217f37caa092bfd477a81a2f41d6ea804e53" 
        ["amount_withdrawn"]=> string(10) "0.00087298" ["amount_sent"]=> string(10) "0.00050000" 
        ["network_fee"]=> string(10) "0.00037298" 
        ["blockio_fee"]=> string(10) "0.00000000" 
    }
}
```

So, you could get `txid` from `$variable->data->txid` but *only* from the original variable. Unlike [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), `var_dump` does not output valid PHP code so you can't get it from that.