# Undefined property: stdClass::$ecompany in C:\wamp64\www\try\insert.php on line 7

Tags: php, stdclass

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb"); // Database Connection 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));// Decoding data
echo '<pre>'; //Printing Array
print_r($data); 
echo '</pre>';
//Getting values in variables
$ename = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data->ename);
$eemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data->eemail);
$ecompany = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data->ecompany);
$edesignation = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data->edesignation);
// Inserting values into Database
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO employee('name', 'email', 'companyName','designation') VALUES('".$ename."','".$eemail."','".$ecompany."','".$edesignation."')");
?>
```

Array Output is - `stdClass Object([ename] => Rohit   [eemail] =>xxxxxxx@gmail.com [ecompanyname] => Seven [edesignation] => Web & Graphic Designer)`

Please help me , what can i do now ?
What is stclass ??

Thanks alot

Comment: You should not share actual email address while posting code :)

Comment: Mean this is no **property  ecompany** in your $data->ecompany

Comment: yes your are right @jigar Shah

Comment: @RohitGautam please avoid asking such questions, try to understand the basics before asking that would be better for your knowledge and future as well. 
You have asked what is stdClass => you can understand about the same here :    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php#992654

Comment: @Adesh Pandey yes you are right. i was only stuck on that problem. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get "ecompany", but that does not exist.
`$ecompany = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data->ecompany);`

In the object it is called "ecompanyname".

So do:
`$ecompany = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data->ecompanyname);`

An explanation of stdClass can be found here [What is stdClass in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was in your question.
The output of **print_r()** statement is:

```
Array Output is - stdClass Object([ename] => Rohit [eemail] => xxxxx@gmail.com [ecompanyname] => Seven [edesignation] => Web & Graphic Designer)
```

So that means your output object has **ecompanyname** instead of **ecompany** as using in the 7th line: *$data->ecompany*

So please change the 7th line to:

```
$ecompany = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data->ecompanyname);
```

That's all!