# Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()

Tags: php, laravel, export-to-excel, laravel-blade

I want to export the table but not all fields have to be exported.
sorry my english is not very good...

**function excel**

```
public function excel()
    {
        $rekanan_internal = rekanan_internal::all();
        $selects = DB::table('rekanan_internal')->select('nama','description','pic','contact')->get();
        $selectsArray = [];
        $selectsArray = ['nama','description','pic','contact'];
        foreach ($selects as $select) 
        {
            $selectsArray = $select->toArray();
        } 

        Excel::create('rekanan_internal', function($excel) use($rekanan_internal){
            $excel->sheet('sheet1',function($sheet) use($selectsArray){
                $sheet->fromArray($rekanan_internal);
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

getting error

> FatalErrorException in ExportController.php line 31: Call to undefined
>   method stdClass::toArray()

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php

Answer (score 4):

`DB::table('xxxx')->get()` will return a collection of `stdClass`. `stdClass` has no function `toArray()`.

You probably want to make an array of the entire collection, in this case, you can replace the for loop with the following:

```
$selectsArray = $selects->toArray();
```

This is because a collection does have a function called [`toArray`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-toarray).

**Update:**
You could even shorten your code to the following:

```
$selectsArray = DB::table('rekanan_internal')
    ->select('nama','description','pic','contact')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

**Update 2:**
For Laravel versions smaller than 5.3, you don't even need to cast the result to an array because the result is an array.

```
$selectsArray = DB::table('rekanan_internal')
    ->select('nama','description','pic','contact')
    ->get()
```

Comment: getting error Call to a member function toArray() on array... broo

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel 5.2 broo

Comment: please help me, from yesterday i've been trying to find fault

Comment: I want to export the table but not all fields must be exported

Comment: Because you are using a Laravel version lower than 5.3, the query builder already returns an array, so you don't need to cast anything. You can use the result directly. And you will only have the fields in your array that you selected using the `select` function.