# Laravel 5.5 Error when trying to fetch data from API for Client Side

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have problem with my code, I can't fetch data from an API to display categories in client side the message "Trying to get property of non-object"

Here is my code:
1. Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Category;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CategoryClientController extends Controller
{
 /**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Category  $category
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Category $category)
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    // Create a request
    $request = $client->get('http://restfulapi.dev/api/categories');
    // Get the actual response without headers
    $response = $request->getBody();

    $categories = json_decode($response,true);

    return view('category.index', compact('categories'));
}
}
```

2. View/index.blade.php to render the results[This is the result when i dd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0c52.png)

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>List of Categories</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   @foreach ($categories as $category)
   {{$category->name}}
   {{$category->description}}
   @endforeach

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Why don't you debug the API response? dd($request) or dd($response) or both to check what comes.

Answer (score 2):

since your response is not [Std Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php) type, you need to use array notation in view when dispaying data, like:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{$category['name']}}
    {{$category['description']}}
@endforeach
```

or return std object from your controller, as:

```
$categories = json_decode($response); //remove true
```