# String to stdClass php

Tags: php, stdclass

I have the following string that corresponds to a JSON object.

```
$string = '{"status": "success", "count": 3, "data": [{"id": 112233}]}'
```

And I would like to cast it to a `stdClass`. My current solution:

```
$object = (object)(array)json_decode($string);
```

While this is functioning, is there a better way? This seems messy and inefficient.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/931419/1531971

Comment: This is not a valid string, because of the quoting, I'll assume that is just a typo `$string = "{"status":...";` vs `$string = '{"status": ...';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much cleaner way would be:

```
$string = '{"status": "success", "count": 3, "data": [{"id": 112233}]}';

$object = json_decode($string);
```

check out what the output for print_r($object); looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => success
    [count] => 3
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 112233
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, creating the associate `array` and passing true to `json_decode`:

```
$string = '{"status": "success", "count": 3, "data": [{"id": 112233}]}';
$object = (object)json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($object);
```

> object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
>     ["status"]=>
>     string(7) "success"
>     ["count"]=>
>     int(3)
>     ["data"]=>
>     array(1) {
>       [0]=>
>       array(1) {
>         ["id"]=>
>         int(112233)
>       }
>     }
>   }