# Default super class in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am doing mostly .NET/Java but now I am doing PHP. I have a class,

```
class MyClass{
    private $data;
    public function __construct(object $data) {        
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
class B{

}

echo new MyClass(new B());
```

When I call this I am getting this error,

> Argument 1 passed to MyClass::__construct() must be an instance of object, instance of B given, called in /run_dir/repl.php(56) : eval()'d code on line 11

In C# the super class is object but don't know why its not work in PHP.

Comment: Funny I get `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class MyClass could not be converted to string in D:\PHP-SOURCE\tst.php on line 12`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php

Comment: Well, when you're using "Object" (literally meaning any in Java), you can simply remove the type since it makes no sense to use it (and you don't have to in PHP).

Comment: Also strange: When I fix the above error by `$x = new MyClass(new B());` I dont get any errors at all???? What version of PHP are you using??

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The `object` type-hint wasn't introduced until PHP 7.2. And note that it still isn't technically a superclass, it just allows passing an instance of any object.

Comment: Using PHP 7.2. Your code will work. Should add `__toString()` method to see the result.

Comment: Yes with Php 7.2 it works but this question is marked as duplicate?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think depend upon version