# How to get stdObject feature from a JSON through PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to get some elements through the CoinMarketCAP API for BitCoin. I would like to print the price feature from the following JSON string:

```
stdClass Object ( [status] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 2020-03-14T12:11:35.816Z [error_code] 
=> 0 [error_message] => [elapsed] => 13 [credit_count] => 1 [notice] => ) [data] => stdClass Object ( 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => Bitcoin [symbol] => BTC [slug] => bitcoin 
[num_market_pairs] => 7807 [date_added] => 2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z [tags] => Array ( [0] => mineable 
) [max_supply] => 21000000 [circulating_supply] => 18270112 [total_supply] => 18270112 [platform] => 
[cmc_rank] => 1 [last_updated] => 2020-03-14T12:10:40.000Z [quote] => stdClass Object ( [USD] => 
stdClass Object ( [price] => 5399.34939057 [volume_24h] => 49810702512.923 [percent_change_1h] => 
-0.117356 [percent_change_24h] => -3.12792 [percent_change_7d] => -40.7189 [market_cap] => 
98646718092.846 [last_updated] => 2020-03-14T12:10:40.000Z ) ) ) ) )
```

I am using the following code, but it's not working:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest';
$parameters = [
  'id' => '1'
];

$headers = [
  'Accepts: application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: xxx'
];
$qs = http_build_query($parameters); // query string encode the parameters
$request = "{$url}?{$qs}"; // create the request URL

$curl = curl_init(); // Get cURL resource

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $request,            // set the request URL
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,     // set the headers 
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1         // ask for raw response instead of bool
));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));// print json decoded response
print_r($response['data']['id']);
curl_close($curl); // Close request
?>
```

Comment: Missing closing quote -> `print_r("$response['data']['id']);`

Comment: was not that, i think it's the structure of the json

Comment: If you have problems, always worth checking what `$response` comes out as (`var_dump($response);` may help).  You output the value using array notation, should be object notation - maybe `print_r($response->data->id);`, but not sure.

Comment: An object of stdClass is [not an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php).

Comment: I also tried to decode it to array. The JSON you have in my question is the result of var_dump @NigelRen

Comment: Looks like `print_r($response->data->{'1'}->id);`