# What does the generic "stdClass" stand for in PHP?

Tags: php, stdclass

The PHP Coders sometimes use them instead of arrays or you get it via json_decode() for example.

But what is the acronym behind **std**?

Is it **St**an**d**ard Class?
But it is not a Base Object Class like in Java for example, where all Objects inherit from it. So maybe there is another written out form?

Comment: It's just a built-in class to create instances from when you cast to object, don't overthink it too much. [Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931407/what-is-stdclass-in-php might be of some help